# Symfony 2.5.6 breaking login?

Tags: symfony, authentication

I'm following the login/security conventions, everything ok with Symfony 2.3 to 2.55 , until I updated to 2.5.6. Now the Login url is displaying:

Neither the property "_username" nor one of the methods "getUsername()", "username()", "isUsername()", "hasUsername()", "__get()" exist and have public access in class "Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Login".

Any idea to solve this?

```
namespace Acme\DemoBundle\Entity;

class Login {
    protected $_username;
    protected $_password;
    protected $_remember_me;

    public function get_Username() {
        return $this->_username;
    }

    public function set_Username($username) {
        $this->_username = $username;
    }

    public function get_Password() {
        return $this->_password;
    }

    public function set_Password($password) {
        $this->_password = $password;
    }

    public function get_RememberMe() {
        return $this->_remember_me;
    }

    public function set_RememberMe($remember) {
        $this->_remember_me = $remember;
    }
}
```

Comment: Git rid of the underscores.  Surprised it worked in 2.3.

Comment: Twig  widget_attributes block overrided for being able to change the name of an input. User & Login no longer uses _username, _password as entity properties/input id. But still use the _username etc, for  input names as required by the symphony login to work. Now the 2.5.6 version is working ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Symfony standard Login needs that you submit a _username and _password named inputs.
Initially my entity user properties were username and password.
Unfortunately I found that twig rendered the inputs ignoring the attr{name='_username'} sent from the formtype builder. So I took the shortcut of renaming the entities properties to the underscore version.
Then everything worked fine until I updated Symfony to 2.5.6 version.
Then as Cerad suggested, I got rid of the entity underscores and form id... but still needed to pass the input names with the underscores. So I overrode this Wig block, just changing the name assignation from the first line to the last one:

```
{% block widget_attributes -%}
id="{{ id }}"
{%- if read_only %} readonly="readonly"{% endif -%}
{%- if disabled %} disabled="disabled"{% endif -%}
{%- if required %} required="required"{% endif -%}
{%- for attrname, attrvalue in attr -%}
    {{- " " -}}
    {%- if attrname in ['placeholder', 'title'] -%}
        {{- attrname }}="{{ attrvalue|trans({}, translation_domain) }}"
    {%- elseif attrvalue is sameas(true) -%}
        {{- attrname }}="{{ attrname }}"
    {%- elseif attrvalue is not sameas(false) -%}
        {{- attrname }}="{{ attrvalue }}"
    {%- endif -%}
{%- endfor -%}
name={{full_name}}
{%- endblock widget_attributes %}
```

Comment: Glad you got it working.  You can also change the parameter name from _username to something that better matches the default form stuff which in turn avoids having to mess with twig.  form_login: username_parameter:  cerad_tourn_account_user_login[username]  http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/security.html#the-login-form-and-process

Comment: Nice idea. Anyway I don't understand why the default usernames are not working unless I override Twig, therefore I think that my solution is not a bad one (although it has been voted negative), because it even add the flexibility of overriding the default name attribute.

Comment: Drive by down votes are always annoying.  Usually it means that the person down voting does not understand the question or the answer so don't take it personally.

Comment: :) Thanks, I was only afraid of missing some important point.

Answer (score 2):

The name of the fields is configurable. You can change `_username` and `_password` fields to anything you want and set them in `security.yml`. For example as I use custom LoginType (alias `login_form`), I have this in `security.yml`:

```
security:
    firewalls:
         secured_area:
             username_parameter: login_form[username]
             password_parameter: login_form[password]
```

This allows me to have `$username` and `$password` variables in the Login Model.